# how to run rails project after doing checkout using svn?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn

i have checked out a rails project into my svn repository.now i want to run that project on my local server.I entered rails server command to run it but i am getting an error that it cant find or read .yml file.what are the steps to be taken after one checks out  some rails project in order to run it on local server.

Comment: Please provide few more details, like version of rail you are running, and what commands you gave, errors you see.

Comment: ubuntu 11.10,rails 3.2.1,ruby 1.8.7,i am using rabbitvcs svn.follwing is the error that i am getting
Cannot find or read /home/user/Niki/alumnicell/config/newrelic.yml
Exiting
can anyone suggest the steps to be followed when you checkout a rails project in order to run it.

Comment: @Nikita Might be a permissions issue now that I see the error. You could try `chmod -R 777 ./config/` from the project root and see if that does anything.

Answer (score 1):

cd into the directory containing the Gemfile and then do either `rails s` or `bundle exec rails s`. The error you are describing usually happens to me when I am not in the same dir as the Gemfile and Rails cannot find the database.yml file.